# como interpretar un while con react

Tags: reactjs

Que tal soy nuevo programando con React y me surgió un inconveniente de como interpretar un ciclo while con react

este un ejemplo que me gustaría hacer con react.

```
 while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<form method="post" action="index.php?p=factura_grabar">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="codigo" value="' . $row["codigo"] . '">';
    echo '<input type="date" name="fecha_emision">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Grabar factura">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado al respecto?

Comment: he intentado con .map

Comment: convendría que aclares exactamente que resultado deseas, por que no queda claro que por lado menciones un código en PHP y luego a react

Comment: const loadFillDataEmpleado = () => {
        return empleado.map((data) => {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <option value={
                        data.nombre
                    }>
                        {
                        data.nombre
                    }</option>
                </Fragment>
            );
        });
    }; pero me sale q empleado no es una funcion

Comment: todo intento va en la pregunta por favor

Comment: esque tengo un ejemplo con php y funciona pero me gustaria realizar el mismo ejemplo con react, solo me gustaria saber como se interpreta el while en react. el ejemplo muestra un folio en un formulario antes de hacer el llenado de este y asi cuando se registra el formulario automaticamente se recarga la pagina y me muestra el folio siguiente

Comment: React es escencialmente JavaScript (*su lenguaje base*) entonces te debe alcanzar con buscar en internet la sintaxis de while en JS y ya solo lo adaptas

Comment: @remikone puedes incluir en la pregunta la estructura de tu arreglo empleado?